# How to select the text box with partial id in the hierarchy in Jquery

Tags: jquery, children, partial, ids

When I found the program Donor Refund, I need to access the input text box which has the partial id "clinic_base_fee_fresh"

[image]

```
$("th[id*='programme_details']").each(function() {
                    var programeName = $(this).html();    
                    if(programeName.indexOf('Donor') > -1){
                        // find the first input with clinic_base_fee_fresh ??                       
                        if($('#programme_details > input:first').attr('id') == 'clinic_base_fee_fresh')
                        {
                            // then select that text box
                            // apply the value "set"
                            //??
                            $('that textbox').val(12);
                        }                       
                        console.log(programeName);
                    }                   
                });
```

Comment: There is a function first() in jquery. Use that to select the correct element and then setting a value is straight forward.

Comment: @Wimanicesir How should I say pick the first input box has partial id clinic_base_fee_fresh

Comment: I created an answer to show how it can be done :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in your first line only

```
$("#programme_details").each(function() {
                var programeName = $(this).html();    
                if(programeName.indexOf('Donor') > -1){
                    // find the first input with clinic_base_fee_fresh ?? 
                    var txtBox = $('[id*=clinic_base_fee_fresh]', $(this));
                    if(txtBox)
                    {
                        // then select that text box
                        // apply the value "set"
                        //??
                        txtBox.val(12);
                    }                       
                    console.log(programeName);
                }                   
            });
```

Comment: var txtBox = $('[id*=clinic_base_fee_fresh]', $(this)); is picking the whole object and it is not applying the value to the text box. I never know that we can write like that though. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```js
// The easiest way is just to select by id, 
// the list will be built in order that it is in the HTML,
// so you can just use this to get the first element:
var html = $('[id*=clinic_base_fee_fresh]')[0];

// However this just gives the HTML, we can still use it though by changing the property
html.value = 'c';

// FOR DEMO REASONS I TIME OUT RIGHT HERE
setTimeout(function(){

  // To get the jQuery object to use jQuery function use this:
  var jquery = $('#programme_details input').first();

  // Now we can use jQuery function val()
  jquery.val('d')

}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="programme_details">
  <input id="1_clinic_base_fee_fresh" value="a"/>
  <input id="2_clinic_base_fee_fresh" value="b"/>
</div>
```

**Documentation:**

[val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

[first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/)